# snprintf generates empty string in android

Tags: android, c++, gcc

I use `snprintf` to generate formatted string:

```
char buf[256];
std::string format_str = getFormatStr(); // "the number is %d", not literal string
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), format_str.c_str(), 10);
```

`getFormatStr()` returns a format string reading from an xml file(**not literal string**), the format string is `"the number is %d"`. On some android phones, I found the `buf` value is empty.The C++ compiler is gcc.

---

**update:**

1. We tested many android phones, and found it is ok on most devices,
   but on one or two devices, the result string is empty.
2. We print the return value of getFormatStr(), the value is right, is
   "the number is %d".

Comment: How do you know that on those android phones the format string isn't an empty string?

Comment: I would expect that for some reason `getFormatStr` is failing to parse the XML file properly.  Perhaps the file is missing, corrupt, using a bad encoding, or perhaps there is some other undefined behaviour in that function which makes it "accidentally work" on all other devices.

Comment: Out of interest, what value is returned from snprintf?

Comment: The value returned from snprintf is 0

Comment: You claim `getFormatStr()` is correct for all platforms, even the ones that don't work. But, did you validate that `format_str` received the right value? Did you validate that `format_str.c_str()` returns the right value? I am not saying these are the problems, I am just saying your validation is incomplete. Also, on the platforms that don't work, does it always work if you use a string literal?